# Assets only compiled after old releases purged when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

...I think that's what's happening anyway.

I'm deploying a Rails app to EC2 with Capistrano. The deployment always succeeds, but even if I've just pushed JS/CSS changes to Git, the assets won't compile the first time. When I kept 5 releases, I had to repeat the deployment until all of the old releases were eventually removed. I reduced it to 3, and then to 1. Now, I see a new version of the JS and CSS after 2 consecutive deployments.

In production there are also multiple `application.js` and `application.css` files in the `shared/public/assets` folder including the latest compiled version. Older versions don't seem to get cleaned unless I run `rake assets:clobber`. `rake assets:clean` doesn't remove them. I assume it's okay to have more than one version of an asset as long as the manifest points at the right file.

I'd really like assets to precompile when there are new changes. Any help would be appreciated.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.9'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'ejs'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
```

**deploy.rb**

```
set :keep_releases, 1

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :cleanup, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**Capistrano Output**

```
INFO [b2b76675] Running RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [b2b76675] Command: cd /var/www/my-app/releases/20150918071822 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2 RAILS_ENV=production RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
INFO [b2b76675] Finished in 2.014 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Comment: Same problem here. 99% of the time Capistrano doesn't recompile assets when I deploy (it ignores CSS / JS changes). At the moment the only patch I have found is to call `rake assets:clobber` in production and then deploy again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are running latest sprockets and sprockets-rails. If you have `tmp/cache` in `linked_dirs`, remove it.

If that fixes it and you want the shared cache back, you can try to write a Capistrano task which deletes the contents of `tmp/cache/assets` at the beginning of deployment.

Comment: I just got around to checking. Removing `tmp/cache` works, but doesn't this mean that it's building assets from scratch with each deployment? I have another project with a similar setup where `tmp/cache` is in `linked_dirs` that doesn't appear to have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I've been wrestling with this one myself recently. After stepping through the sprockets codebase, I noted that the cache wasn't properly getting expired. The only fix I could find was forcing a complete rebuild each time.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wish there was a better solution, but this worked for me. Will update if I come across anything.